# curl google maps not working share hosting server

Tags: curl, google-maps-api-3, php-curl

I tried to get Google Maps with postcode using curl before it worked properly, but now it is not working, it gives me random Google Maps position.

The following code is used on this [website](http://www.questresidential.co.uk/detail.php?rent_buy=rent&for_let=&id=154).

```php
function map_apper($address,$big=""){
    $address = str_replace(" ","+",$address);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $xml = curl_exec($ch);
    //Use SimpleXML library to get the data from the XML string
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $lat = $xml->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat;
    $lng = $xml->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng;
    $coords = $lat . "," . $lng;

    curl_close($ch); //Close the CURL instance, to keep things tidy
    $output =  "<iframe class=\"google_map\"";
    if(!empty($big)){
        $output .= "id='big_map'";
    }
    $output .= " frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"yes\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" src=\"https://maps.google.com/?q= {$lat},{$lng}&amp;ie=UTF8&z=16&output=embed\"></iframe>";   
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a random position?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [key in your request, from the web service documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key):

> All Geocoding API applications should use an API key. Including a key in your request:
>
> Allows you to monitor your application's API usage in the Google Developers Console.
> Enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits.
>
> Ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary.